# Qwerty keyboard is showing on Oppo, when it should be a numerical keyboard

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, keyboard, oppo

My EditText has an `inputType="numberPassword"`and I've tested this on many devices and it shows correctly (a numerical keyboard), BUT on an **Oppo device** it just shows a qwerty keyboard.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/dit_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:hint="@string/pin_login"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:letterSpacing="0.2"
            android:maxLength="4" />
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try using AppcompatEditText

Comment: did you use android keyboard apps or custom keyboard in your oppo phone?

Comment: @NoName i used android keyboard

Comment: try to uninstall and re install again the application. I think their something in your oppo phone. No issue in your code.